# Highstock title and subtitle overlap

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've got the following in my highcharts options:

```
subtitle : {
    text : 'Source: WindLogics',
    x : -20
},
title : {
    text : 'Loading',
    x : -20
},
```

Most of the time, this looks the way I expect with the Title above the Subtitle above the chart.

However, I have two charts on the page with only one displayed at a time.  Sometimes when the chart comes into view, it is rendered as shown below with the Title and Subtitle on top of each other and both are within the chart rather than above it.

I am calling setText and redraw while the chart container has display = none.

Looks like this:

[image: title and subtitle munged into chart]

I'm using highstock 1.3.9 (highcharts 3.0.9).

Comment: Could you upgrade to 1.3.10 version of Highstock? If this won't help, could you recreate issue on jsFiddle? Simple demo works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/104/ It may be also the same as [this bug](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2267).

Comment: Yes, that bug you refer to looks exactly like what I am seeing... except that I'm not using 'useHTML'.

Comment: Pawel, I'm about to try some of the workarounds mentioned in that bug.  If you post them here as an answer and they work for me, I'll accept your answer.  Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to test and then accept your own answer, since they aren't mine workaround ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not using 'useHTML' but my problem seems otherwise to be the same that is [reported here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2267).

For me, the fix was to use the cloneRenderTo method.

```
chart.cloneRenderTo(); // https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2267
chart.setTitle({
    text : 'Title',
    x : -20
}, false);
chart.redraw();
chart.cloneRenderTo(true);
```

For some reason, I needed to call redraw separately from the setTitle otherwise a resize browser event was required before the chart data would display.

Thanks to [Pawel Fus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1451635/pawel-fus) for the pointer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style the title/subtitle, put them in a `<div>`.

```
subtitle : {
    text : '<div id="subtitle">Source: WindLogics</div>',
    x : -20
},
title : {
    text : '<div id="title">Loading</div>',
    x : -20
},
```

You can then style the titles to your likings (including margins, padding etc.).

Comment: Unfortunately, the image hasn't shown up yet.  Not sure why.

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle for us? That way we can check what could be wrong (if it's not just a bug in Highstock 1.3.9).

Comment: I'll try.  Unfortunately, it's a bit complicated to reproduce for the reasons described in the OP.

Comment: Hmmm.  I was calling Chart.setTitle("...") just before calling redraw.  I just changed that to Chart.setTitle("...", false) and I haven't seen this ugliness since that change.  I'll wait a while and see if the problem pops up again before calling this a solution because it doesn't make sense (to me) that an extra redraw should make this happen.

Comment: This isn't a direct solution to your problem; it might be a work around :).